# Select data from table throws error in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I am a beginner trying to execute a simple web application using Pyramid and SQLAlchemy. As of now my app just returns all data stored in my table.

My views.py:

```
@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='templates/trial.pt')
def my_view(request):
    try:
        #str=Mystring(name="second",data="Hellostring")
        #DBSession.add(str)
        myvar=Mystring.query.order_by(Mystrings.data)

    except DBAPIError:
        return Response(conn_err_msg, content_type='text/plain', status_int=500)
    #return {'project': 'Alpy'}
    return {'myvar':myvar}
```

My template:-

```
<body>
    <div id="middle">
      <div class="middle align-right">
        <div id="left" class="app-welcome align-left">
          You can return to the
          <a href="${request.application_url}">FrontPage</a>.<br/>
<div tal:condition="myvar">
Your selection returns:<br><tal:block tal:content="myvar"></tal:block>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

my model.py:-

```
class Mystring(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mystrings'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)
    data = Column(Text)
```

My error is: `AttributeError: type object 'Mystring' has no attribute 'query'`

I tried this. "myvar=DBSession.query(Mystring).all()" the error went away but I get

```
Your selection returns:
[alpy.models.Mystring object at xxxx, alpy.models.Mystring object at xxxxx]
```

which is not what i intended to get. I wanted a name value pair.

Please help.

Comment: I have edited my question please check.

Comment: Good change, I was going to suggest it (you run the query method on a session instance). You get a list of objects as you haven't requested which field of the object you want. You can write something like this:

[x.name for x in myvar] and you get a list of names. Similarly with the data field.

You can also use a normal for loop for this but using a list comprehension is a great python idiom.

Comment: Thank you. But how do i send them all with the response dictionary? and am i supposed to substitute x with the classname Mystring?

Comment: Do you want to send a list of (name, data) pairs? If so, you can do it like this: 
`[(x.name, x.data) for x in myvar]`
Also `x` is just a local variable for the list comprehension, so it can be anything you like, or just leave it as `x`.

Comment: Okay that worked perfectly. Thank you. Can u please suggest any good learning sites for pyra-sqlalchemy apart from the url dispatch tutorial thats already available?

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't used pyramid yet, only sqlalchemy. For sqlalchemy I can recommend the official basics tutorial at: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html as I used that to learn. It covers the basics very nicely. I'm glad that it worked, I'll add an answer below that I described so that if anybody has a similar problem they can find it more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a list of objects from sqlalchemy. If you just need the data, and you want to return a list of (name, data) pairs, you can do it with a list comprehension like this: 

`return [(x.name, x.data) for x in myvar]`

Note: `x` is just a local variable for the list comprehension, so it can be any name you like.

There is some great documentation for sqlalchemy basics at the official site, here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html